# Get video frames from webcam in HTML and use it for OPENCV python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, html, opencv

I know it may sound very simple for most of you but i need to get video (Frame by frame) from HTML or java script and use it in python OPENCV.
I am already experienced with python OPENCV, Deeplearning etc but i have no idea about HTML or JS and how to use Frame from any device(Mobile,Laptop) camera.
I need to make python app. So need to know some way to get frame from HTML and use it in python code.
Thank you in advance for all the help.

Comment: Why not use OPENCV directly ? (`cv2.VideoCapture()`)

Comment: Will it work in html page?

Comment: HTML is a markup language, it doesn't have any image processing library.

Answer (score 0):

So i actually used html getmedia to get webcam/camera feed (using JS). Then i used that image in byte format. Convert it in PIL/opencv, preprocess it (or do whatever i want) and turned it back in bytes for html page viewing.

Comment: can you share the code link or something?